# 'in <string>' type error: How to compare input string to a list(array)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a list of string values and compare the input from console with the list and return the value + return it. Like the error msg suggested, I have tried different ways such as including `str(var)` type casting, but it results in '`can't assign to function cal`'. What is my error here.

```
In [14]: IDList = ["0002","0001"]
    ...: 
    ...: def getID():
    ...:     ID = input("Type in serial no. to use --> ")
    ...:     for e in IDList:
    ...:         if ID in e:
    ...:             Analyze = e
    ...:             break
    ...:         else:
    ...:             pass
    ...:     print "Analyzing ID no.", Analyze
    ...:     return Analyze

In [15]: getID()

Type in serial no. to use --> 0002
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-c3fcb5192f61>", line 1, in <module>
    getID()

  File "<ipython-input-14-3026f1ad3d65>", line 12, in getID
    if ID in e:

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: 1. Use `raw_input`, not `input`, in Python 2.x. 2. What don't you get about the error message? `ID` is an integer and `e` is a string, so `ID in e` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` will interpret `0002` as an int.  You should use `raw_input()` instead to interpret `0002` as a string.

```
def getID():
    ID = raw_input("Type in serial no. to use --> ")
    for e in IDList:
        if ID in e:
            Analyze = e
            break
        else:
            pass
    print "Analyzing ID no.", Analyze
    return Analyze
```